# Is there a way to easilly create union type from enum in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, union

often when I'm writing Typescript I'm running into situations where I have enum of some sort and from this enum I want to generate union type. I tried looking for utility type which would do it for me but I wasn't able to find any. Is there an easier way of doing so?

```
enum Person {
  Name = "Adam",
  Age = 32
}

type Something = Person.Name | Person.Age;
```

I know that this example is rather simple but often I have enums with a tone of entries and doing it by hand is neither enjoyable nor maintainable.

Comment: `Person` is a type. In fact, in your last line typescript actually returns this `type Something = Person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum type is itself already equivalent to the union of all members of that enum.

You can even see this in action if you try to use `Exclude` to remove a member from the enum:

```
enum Person {
  Name = "Adam",
  Age = 32
}

type Something = Exclude<Person, Person.Age> // Person.Name
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACsBOBnA9iKBvAUFKA5AhhMFALxQBEAggCaHkA02UlA5sWQMwBMmAvppgAuATwAOxAMrIiggBYBLEC1JQAogA8AxgBsw1YAB44SVPVgIUIAHStgAPigB6R+ZPWCRIA)

Comment: Thanks!
If I could I would up vote this